# Where HTML5 Application Cache file store in client side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying **[HTML5 Application Cache DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp)**

**Where all above cached file store in client side ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="demo_html.appcache">
<body>
<script src="demo_time.js">
</script>
<p id="timePara"><button onclick="getDateTime()">Get Date and Time</button></p>
<p><img src="img_logo.gif" width="336" height="69"></p>
<p>Try opening <a href="tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm" target="_blank">this page</a>, then go offline, and reload the page. The script and the image should still work.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question is: why do you want to know? What problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried?

Comment: i want to check that cached html file is minified or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968862/html5-application-cache-manifest-file-location-on-hard-drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location depends on different types of browser, HTML specification not forces browser vendors, for instance, [`the location in Firefox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache):

> Windows Vista/7:
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\.\OfflineCache
>
> Mac/Linux:
>   /Users//Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/./OfflineCache